# Passing a string array to stored procedure

Tags: arrays, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

To start, I understand this question has been asked several times previously, but other posts seem to come from a source language, possibly c# or something else.
I have no such luxury.

Basically I am writing a stored proc in SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProc 
    @MyDate DATETIME,
    @StringVariable1 nvarchar(50),
    @StringVariable2 nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
 ...  do my stored proc
END
```

Typically to fire the stored proc I am given

```
EXEC MyStoredProc '2018-05-09 00:00:00', 'Heres a string', ('aaa','bbb','eee')
```

So I have no way of altering the EXEC statement or the values getting passed into the stored proc.  I only have ability to modify the stored procedure.
As you can see, @StringVariable2 is coming through as an array of string values.  I need to read each element of the array individually to perform the necessary functionality of the stored proc.
As am example, lets say I have a table with the following columns

```
ITEM
DESCRIPTION
Feature1
Feature2
Feature3
Feature4
```

I need to write a where clause which would be something like

```
SELECT * from MyTable where Feature1 = @FirstArrayElement and Feature2 = @SecondArrayElement and Feature3 = @ThirdArrayElement
```

Just not sure how I can tweak the stored procedure to split the elements into different strings.
As an FYI, the EXEC command is coming from Crystal Reports.

Comment: You can't fire your SP with a parenthesis enclosing values like your example. You will have to wrap the 3rd parameter in a string and might need to escape the inner single quotes with an additional quote on each occurrence `'(''aaa'',''bbb'',''eee'')'`

Comment: Unfortunately I have no way of altering what is getting passed to the stored proc.  I can't wrap the parameter in single quotes.

Comment: Then your Stored Procedure will never work.  What is calling this SP/how is it being called?  From a C# application?  From another Stored Procedure?  From a website?  How/where?

Comment: @YoufahMizzum this is gonna generate a parse error. If you can't change it then it will never work, as it's not the correct syntax as Brad said. You can't recieve a parameter which is a combination of parameters (unless its a table data type, in which this syntax isn't correct also).

Comment: If he fixes it so it can be passed correctly without the syntax error, you can parse out the comma string like in my answer below and use those as parameters (thought that was the original question), or convert it to a table type parameter and have the C# app pass a SQL table type (google SQL Table Type) will give you examples of that.  Then you can use that as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to parse the data from a string into a table data type.  So you pass it the string and the delimiter, in my example it will split the states into a table to select from.

```
Select * FROM dbo.fn_splitDelimitedInotTable('MI,AR,TE', ',')


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_splitDelimitedInotTable](
    @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml XML
    SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'
    INSERT INTO @t(val)
    SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') AS item
    FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') AS records(r)
    RETURN
END
```

so if your parameter has this string value in it you would call the function like this with the where id = 1 to get first paramater:

```
Select * FROM dbo.fn_splitDelimitedInotTable('aaa','bbb','eee', ',') where id=1
```

would return aaa

then

```
Select * FROM dbo.fn_splitDelimitedInotTable('aaa','bbb','eee', ',') where id=2
```

would return bbb

and so on

-----  UPDATED to show what I added to comments

```
-- recreate the varaible from the SP passed (using double quotes for escape characters to create the data that is passed)

DECLARE @StringVariable2 nvarchar(1000)
SET @StringVariable2 = '(''aaa'',''bbb'',''eee'')'

-- this statement removes the parens
SET @StringVariable2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(@StringVariable2, '(', ''), ')', '') 

-- just test selects it with no parems
SELECT @StringVariable2

-- returns the first vaiable from the string so 'aaa'
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_splitDelimitedInotTable(@StringVariable2, ',') where id=1
```

Comment: And how would I use that in the stored procedure?

Comment: Edited answer to give specific examples from your logic

Comment: But the stored proc parameter @StringVariable2 is expecting a string.  It's not coming through as a string.  It's coming as ('string1','string2','string3').  How do I deal with that?

Comment: That is a string still, it has the parens in it?  You could replace the parens on the string then call the function how I described above.  do a replace like this on your variable then call my function:  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@StringParamater, '(', ''), ')', '')  this will replace the parens

Comment: I can't replace the parens.  Don't forget, I have no way of altering how the EXEC MyStoredProc is formulated.  I have no access to any underlying programming language.  i.e the 3rd parameter of the stored proc @StringVariable2 will always be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: Yes but you can edit the SP right?  That line of code in my comment will remove the parens in the SP after it is passed to the SP

Comment: I added the code from my comments to my answer to show how to remove the parens.  If you create the function and run the code above it will show you the results.  Then you can see how it works and include it in your SP

Comment: Your examples are excellent and helpful, but it still doesn't overcome the problem that the SP is expecting a nvarchar(1000) string.  I am NOT passing in a string wrapped in single quotes.  It is wrapped in parens.   I am just getting an error Incorrect syntax near '('.    Which is fair enough because the left parens isn't a string character.  The problem may be the datatype of @StringVariable2.  Maybe it shouldn't be nvarchar(1000)?

Comment: nvarchar  is a string, see my example I added to the bottom, I declared the variable as nvarchar (matching your SP declaration).    So you are saying the value being passed to the SP  does not have a single quote around it?  You cant do that, it has to have a single quote around the string or else you cant pass it to the SP, that is your problem.  To pass a string in SQL you have to have single quote around it

Comment: Yes!  I am exactly saying that the value being passed to the SP does not have single quotes around it.  It has parentheses around it.  I already know that is the problem.  My question was to find a solution!

Comment: Who ever calls the SP in code will be passing it in a variable and SQL will get it and it wont have the single quotes around it when the C# app calls the SP.  For you to test/play with it in SQL though you have to put the single quotes around it, they are not actually part of the value/string, that is just how SQL works you must have single quotes around a string, they do not become part of the sting value though when doing comparrisons or inserting into tables.  so if you inserted the @StringParmater = '(testdata)' into a table it would only insert (testdata),  without the single quotes

Comment: How is the SP being called?  From C# or from SQL?  You can not call the SP in SQL by passing a string value without single quotes around it.  If an application is calling the Stored Procedure it should not need single quotes around it (in C# it would have double quotes around it) that is how values are set in different languages.